# android.view.InflateException: GridAdapter

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview

I am working with a gridview and i want to show images and text in gridview using adapter and I can't understand why it's crashing.
There is a error in GridAdapter.java.and
I don't know why this code give me NullPointerException with a gridview

Below is my code:

GridAdapter.java

```
    public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    private final String[] web;
    private final int[] Imageid;

    public GridAdapter(Context c,String[] web,int[] Imageid ) {
        mContext = c;
        this.Imageid = Imageid;
        this.web = web;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {

            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
            TextView textView = (TextView) grid.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.pic);
            textView.setText(web[position]);
            imageView.setImageResource(Imageid[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }

        return grid;
    }
}
```

GridActivity.java

```
public class GridActivity extends Activity {
GridView simpleGrid;
String[] web = {"Google", "Github", "Instagram", "Facebook"} ;
int[] imageId = {R.drawable.product_imag,R.drawable.product_imag,R.drawable.product_imag,R.drawable.product_imag};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gridview);
    simpleGrid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv);

    GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(GridActivity.this, web, imageId);
    simpleGrid.setAdapter(adapter);
    simpleGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(GridActivity.this, "You Clicked at " +web[+ position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}
```

}

EDIT Griditem.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e6e6e6"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="1dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="1.5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/pic"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/product_imag"/>

        <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:background="#e6e6e6"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/product_name"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="New text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/product_price"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="New Text"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/product_other"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/product_name"
                android:text="New Text" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

activity_gridview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Vertical space between grid items -->
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/gv"
        android:verticalSpacing="50dp"></GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my LogCat

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: android.mendonca.averdapp, PID: 6640

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:761)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
at android.mendonca.averdapp.activity.GridAdapter.getView(GridAdapter.java:55)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2427)
at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1065)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:19881)
```

Comment: Please post your grid_item file

Comment: This error says  `Binary XML file line #24:` and you did not post xml class, how will some tell solution?

Comment: I posted the code of grid_item and activity_gridview

Comment: In grid_item file, `View` should be capital

Answer (score 1):

Try using View element instead of view in your grid_item.xml at line #24.

Answer (score 0):

Maby You need to overide you methods

```
  @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return web[position];
    }

 @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Imageid[position];
    }
```

Comment: still not working but thanx

Comment: I got the solution anyway it's in grid_item where view element is created I just removed it working fine now

Comment: oh i see it is name of Griditem not equals to grid_item